# Calculate PI using OpenMP task directive

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp, pi

I need to parallelize code that calculates number **π** using Leibniz formula for **π** with OpenMP task directive.

[Leibniz formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTwkw.png)

So, I got a sequential code:

```
double sequential_execution(long long n)
{
    long long i;
    double factor;
    double sum = 0.0;
    double startTime = omp_get_wtime();

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        factor = (i % 2 == 0) ? 1.0 : -1.0;
        sum += factor / (2 * i + 1);
    }
    double endTime = omp_get_wtime();
    printf("Sequential execution took %f seconds\n", endTime - startTime);
    sum = 4.0 * sum;
    return sum;
}
```

My first idea was to capture content of for loop as a single task with n = 100000000:

```
double parallel_execution(long long n)
{
    long long i=0;
    double factor;
    double sum = 0.0;
    long long index; 
    long squareRootN = ceil(sqrt(n));

    double startTime = omp_get_wtime();
#pragma omp parallel default(none) private(i,factor) shared(n,sum) 
{
    #pragma omp single
    {
        for ( i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            #pragma omp task
            {
                factor = (i % 2 == 0) ? 1.0 : -1.0;
                #pragma omp atomic
                sum += factor / (2 * i + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
    double endTime = omp_get_wtime();
    printf("Parallel execution took %f seconds\n", endTime - startTime);
    sum = 4.0 * sum;
    return sum;
}
```

But sequential execution was way way faster.(Seq. time: 0.3 s, Par. time: 87 s)

Second idea was to increase granularity of one task and decrease number of tasks in a way where one for loop that goes from 0 do n-1 was split into two nested loops where each one goes from 0 to sqrt(n)-1. Now, each task has for loop that goes from 0 to sqrt(n)-1, and sqrt(n) tasks are generated, again for n = 100000000.

```
double parallel_execution(long long n)
{
    long long i=0;
    double factor;
    double sum = 0.0;
    long long index; 
    long squareRootN = ceil(sqrt(n));

    double startTime = omp_get_wtime();
#pragma omp parallel default(none) shared(sum,n,squareRootN) private(i,factor,index)
{
    #pragma omp single
    {
        for (i=0;i<squareRootN;i++)
        #pragma omp task
        {
            for (long j=0;j<squareRootN;j++)
            {
                index = i*squareRootN + j;
                if (index > n) break;
                factor = (index % 2 == 0)?1.0 : -1.0; 
                #pragma omp atomic
                sum += factor / (2*index + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
    double endTime = omp_get_wtime();
    printf("Parallel execution took %f seconds\n", endTime - startTime);
    sum = 4.0 * sum;
    return sum;
}
```

Now, I got better time, but again it was way slower than sequential execution(Seq : 0.3s, Par : 11s).

At this point, I'm starting to think that it's not possible to get speed-up using task directive, but again, is there something that I did wrong or is there some way to restructure the problem to get better performances ?
Thanks

Edit:
Best function so far:

```
double parallel_execution(long long n)
{
    double factor;
    int totalThreads = 0;
    long squareRootN = ceil(sqrt(n));
    double master_sum = 0;
    double *sum;
    double startTime = omp_get_wtime();
#pragma omp parallel default(none) shared(sum,n,squareRootN,totalThreads) private(factor)
{
    #pragma omp single
    {
        totalThreads = omp_get_num_threads();
        sum = (double*)calloc(totalThreads,sizeof(double));
        for (long long i=0;i<squareRootN;i++)
        #pragma omp task
        {
            for (long long j=0;j<squareRootN;j++)
            {
                long long index = i*squareRootN + j;
                if (index > n) break;
                factor = (index % 2 == 0)?1.0 : -1.0; 
                sum[omp_get_thread_num()] += factor / (2*index + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
    for (int i=0;i<totalThreads;i++) master_sum += sum[i];
    double endTime = omp_get_wtime();
    printf("Parallel execution took %f seconds\n", endTime - startTime);
    master_sum*=4;
    return master_sum;
}
```

Input size: n = 1000000000
Seq. time: 3.19 s
Par. time: 4 s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are *paying* the overheads of the `atomic` operation and [task creation and management.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14736594/openmp-recursive-tasks-example-slower-than-sequential) You can get a better speedup with a simpler `parallel for` with reduction, namely:

```
#pragma omp parallel default(none) shared(n) reduction( + : sum ) 
for ( i = 0; i < n; i++) {
     double factor = (i % 2 == 0) ? 1.0 : -1.0;
     sum += factor / (2 * i + 1);
}
```

We can slightly improve the sequential code by separating beforehand the odds from the evens:

```
#pragma omp parallel default(none) shared(n, sum) nowait
{
     #pragma omp for reduction( + : sum ) 
     for (int i = 0; i < n; i+=2 ) {
        sum += 1.0 / (2 * i + 1);
    }
    #pragma omp for reduction( + : sum ) 
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i += 2) {
        sum += -1.0 / (2 * i + 1);
    }
}
```

You can improve it further by having a single loop *for* performing the even and odds computation for each iteration of that loop.

You do not need to make the `'i'` from the loop `private`, it will be implicitly `private` in OpenMP.

If you *really* have to use tasks, you can try to minimize the synchronization overhead by replicating the variable `sum` among threads, and reduce it manually at the end of the `parallel region`, (I am assuming `n >= 2` and `n` being `even` just for simplicity sake):

```
double sum[total_threads];

#pragma omp parallel default(none) shared(n, sum)
{
    int threadID = omp_get_thread_num();
    sum[threadID] = 0.0;
    #pragma omp single
    {
        for ( i = 0; i < n; i+=2) {
            #pragma omp task
            {
                sum[threadID] += 1.0 / (2 * i + 1);
                sum[threadID] += -1.0 / (2 * (i + 1) + 1);
            }
        }
    }
  }

double master_sum = 0.0;
for(int i = 0; i < total_threads; i++)
    master_sum += sum[i];
```

If you are using a `C` compiler that supports OpenMP `4.5` you can use a more sophisticated constructor, namely [`taskloop Construct`](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu47.html), and combined it with the `reduction` of the variable `sum`.